# Python: Web scraping shopify site

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to web scraping many websites, but one of these is "Lime Crime" that is supported by Shopify (AFAIK). I'm using lxml library, but when I tried to use xpath to go to an element I got an empty array, but It actually exists in web page.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = "https://limecrime.com/collections/unicorn-hair-full-coverage"
response = requests.get(url)
byte_data = response.content
source_code = html.fromstring(byte_data)
```

I've tried `source_code.cssselect("a.CF-Product__ImageWrapper")` or `source_code.cssselect("CF-Product__ImageWrapper")`, but It didn't work.
Could any one help me to get all the links of products?

Answer (score 2):

This might be simply because the content you are looking for is loaded at a second stage with some Javascript, but is **not** there in the html page at your specified url.

There is no way to do this with `response`: the data is not there. As an alternative, you can look into `headless chrome automation`. Libraries that come to mind, `puppeteer` and the Python version, `pyppeteer`.

A headless browser library allows you to essentially run an instance of a full browser, which will parse and download every resource just as a you would see on screen, and provide you a full DOM in the end to parse.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check and considerated it for my solution. I was expecting to get something without another library. But I understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. You are probably trying to parse an element that is either being generated in Javascript, or at least having its class assigned in Javascript.

`lxml` will not run Javascript code, it will just parse the raw HTML you downloaded from that URL. You can take a look on the HTML via terminal:

```
curl -s "https://limecrime.com/collections/unicorn-hair-full-coverage" | grep "CF-Product__ImageWrapper"
```

You can see it returns zero lines.

If you want to take a look on the actual response, you can use just:

`curl -s "https://limecrime.com/collections/unicorn-hair-full-coverage"`

This will show you exactly what is being parsed by your code.

Answer (score -1):

To get  the source code of pages
You can use requests and BeautifulSoup

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://limecrime.com/collections/unicorn-hair-full-coverage"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
print (soup)
```

Comment: Hi, yes, that code works. But my problem is related with javascript content loaded. Thank you.